# Messages Processors get dormant in MI 4.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

On Micro Integrator 4.1 we are getting some message processors (MP) somehow stuck, meaning that they are not picking messages from the queue after some time. It’s like these MPs get dormant.

We have to disable these MPs and reenable them to get them to pick the messages from the queue again.

We don’t see this happening in Enterprise Integrator 6.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: Can't see anything in the logs. We suspect that the consumer was down and message processor tried to deliver the message many times and stop trying. Ideally it should keep trying indefinitely until consumer gets online

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the default behavior of the message processor by setting different properties. Have a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/message-processors/msg-sched-forwarding-processor-properties/#optional-properties).